# Splitter with panel scroll

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a two panel, panel1 is a form and panel2 is a command.

panel1 I enable auto scroll to `true`, and dock is `fill`

panel2 I set auto scroll `false`, and dock is `right`

I add splitter in right of panel1 and when running the program, the result is:

[image]

The scroll vertical place in the right and scroll horizontal also drag panel 2 too.

I want the form splitcontainer to be like this:

[image]

How to do that without using splitcontainer, only splitter and two panels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following in order:

1. panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
2. splitter1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
3. panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

If you **added** your controls in the order different from `panel1, splitter1, panel2`, you can do the following to re-order them:

1. Select `panel1`, right-click -> *Bring to Front*
2. Select `splittler1`, right-click -> *Bring to Front*
3. Select `panel2`, right-click -> *Bring to Front*

Comment: @Alexbelek could you point out what scroll? `Vertical scroll` or `Horizontal scroll`? Is it scroll of `panel1`? screen shot would better describe your current situation.

Comment: im sory , the splitter can't drag @King king

Comment: @Alexbelek how did you know that? do you see where it is on your form? I've tested the simple code and of course the `Splitter` can be dragged well.

Comment: @Alexbelek you should check the `AutoSize` of your `panel1` and `panel2`, it should be `false`. Also check the `MaximumSize` of them.

Comment: Why panel1 is left? how about panel1 is fill and panel2 is right? like my question?

Comment: @Alexbelek it's OK, but you have to change the order to `BringToFront` like this `panel2, splitter1, panel1` and **note that** `splitter1.Dock = DockStyle.Right` in that case.

Comment: its awesome, step by step i try with your last comment and its work, how it works?

Comment: @Alexbelek it works by how the `Dock` and `Z-index order` is applied, it's a little complicated to explain, you can imagine it's done step-by-step, when a control is added first, it will **occupy** some **space**, the next control is added will use **the remaining space**, ... the last control should use **all the remaining space** and hence, its **Dock** is `Fill`.

Answer (score 4):

you first add split container to form then in panel one of split container add simple panel and set few property of that panel to

1: auto scroll  to true.

2: dockstyle to fill

you will get the desired output..

Comment: the OP stated clearly that **How to do that without using `splitcontainer`**?

Comment: Even though this does not answer the OP, it helped me because I am using a `SplitContainer`.