# Resizing panel in winforms when splitter moves

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a three panel inside the panel named `panelbase`

[image]

I try with

panel `left` dock is `left`

panel `right` dock is `right` and

panel `button` is `fill`.

but the button position is not in the center.

here is the capture

[image: Image2]

How to resize panel `left` and panel `right`, when I drag a splitter, the panel button position always in center?

Comment: your screen shot shows that your button looks like centered?

Comment: @KingKing wait, i update the question

Comment: Why not use a Table Layout and set the center column to an absolute value (i.e. the width of your buttons), and the left and right values to say, 100%?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Anchor` property for your `buttons`. First, make it centered, then do this:

```
button1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
```

To make your button centered using code you can do something like this:

```
button1.Left = (buttonPanel.Width - button1.Width)/2;
```

Comment: @Alexbelek just in `Form Load`, you can center your `Buttons` at design time and you don't need any code to center them. If you add them by code, you can center them by code (as I pointed out). The only code you need is `button.Anchor = ...`, you can add that code after your buttons are centered. (just 1 time)

Comment: @Alexbelek It's hard to tell you how to make it work, I've just made a demo for you at here http://www.mediafire.com/download/sul67je9c1a9832/AutoCenter_with_Anchor_-_Demo.zip

Comment: @Alexbelek the project I made is just in `VS 2008`, there will be a `Conversion dialog` appeared to ask you for converting to `VS 2010 project`. you just need to click `Finish`.

Comment: i use splitter. you use spitcontainer, i still follow you since http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862440/splitter-with-panel-scroll . i follow your code and project and still same.

Comment: @Alexbelek it's almost the same. Here is the updated demo using `Splitter` instead http://www.mediafire.com/?iv16exw37hklccm **You can set Anchor in the Properties window at design time or Use the code I posted (of course the Buttons should be centered first at design time or use code**